# MySQL trigger to update a column by reordering its values

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-trigger

Sorry if the title is miss-leading, I couldn't come up with a better one that is related to my issue.

I've been trying to solve this for a while now, and I couldn't find the solution.

I have a table `categories`:

```
+----+--------+----------+
| ID |  Name  | Position |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 | Dogs   |        4 |
|  2 | Cats   |        3 |
|  3 | Birds  |       10 |
|  4 | Others |        2 |
+----+--------+----------+
```

I need to keep the Position column in order, in a way not to miss an values as well, so the final table should look like:

```
+----+--------+----------+
| ID |  Name  | Position |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 | Dogs   |        3 |
|  2 | Cats   |        2 |
|  3 | Birds  |        4 |
|  4 | Others |        1 |
+----+--------+----------+
```

What I tried doing, is creating a trigger on UPDATE and on INSERT that would try to prevent this. The trigger I created ( same one before INSERT) :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER sortPostions BEFORE UPDATE ON categories
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET @max_pos = 0;
  SET @min_pos = 0;
  SET @max_ID = 0;
  SET @min_ID = 0;
  SELECT position, id INTO @max_pos,@max_ID FROM categories WHERE position = ( SELECT MAX(position) FROM categories);
  SELECT position, id INTO @min_pos,@min_ID FROM categories WHERE position = ( SELECT MIN(position) FROM categories);

  IF NEW.position >= @max_pos AND NEW.id != @max_ID THEN 
    SET NEW.position = @max_pos + 1; 
  END IF;

  IF NEW.position <= @min_pos AND NEW.id != @min_ID THEN 
    SET NEW.position = @min_pos - 1; 
  END IF;

  IF NEW.position < 0 THEN
    SET NEW.position = 0;
  END IF;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

But unfortunately it's not working as intended. It's not fixing missing values and I think this is not a perfect solution.

I went ahead and created a procedure:

```
BEGIN
    SET @n = 0;
    UPDATE categories
    SET position = @n:=@n+1
    ORDER BY position ASC;
END
```

But I wasn't able to call this procedure from a trigger, as it seems that MySQL doesn't allow that. I get the following error:

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'categories' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

mysql -V output:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.57, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
```

What's the perfect solution to solve this problem ?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not aware of a restriction in MySQL against calling stored procedures from triggers.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm getting the following error: #1442 - Can't update table 'categories' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think this is happening because the trigger/procedure is going into an infinite loop, where the procedure is triggering the trigger again.

Comment: MySQL does not allow you to change, in the same table, a different row other than the one row that the trigger is executed for. So you cannot do what you want to do (adjust every other row on update) with a trigger. You'll have to do it after you updated the row (by e.g. calling your procedure in a seperate query, or by doing every change to that table in a procedure). Or: don't do it at all, but use e.g. `order by position, id`. It'll have the same effect, and you can do the same things with it. If you want it to look nice, you'll have to live with doing it in 2 steps (or not use MySQL).

Comment: @Solarflare I need this only for the visual effect when the columns are selected, as this will be used in a CMS where clients can sort the categories. I think I should do this using PHP after every update/insert of a category. I just wanted to go the "geek" way and do this through MySQL directly. Thanks for the answer, I'll keep this open as I'm welcoming any new idea.

Comment: Just to make sure you did not misunderstand me: you don't have to do much in php (although you obviously can do it there). I meant: you can just replace "update table ..." (which you want to automatically execute the reorder procedure, which is not possible) by "update table ...; call reorder_procedure();" (same for inserts and deletes), so instead of executing one `insert`, you execute two queries, one `insert` and one procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in a trigger. MySQL does not allow you to do an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE in a trigger (or in a procedure called by the trigger) against the same table for which the trigger was spawned.

The reason is that it can result in infinite loops (your update spawns the trigger, which updates the table, which spawns the trigger again, which updates the table again...). Also because it can create lock conflicts if more than one of these requests happens concurrently.

You should do this in application code if you must renumber the position of the rows. Do it with a separate statement after your initial query has completed.

Another option is don't worry about making the positions consecutive. Just make sure they are in the right order. Then when you query the table, generate row numbers on demand.

```
SELECT (@n:=@n+1) AS row_num, c.*
FROM (SELECT @n:=0 AS n) AS _init
CROSS JOIN categories AS c
ORDER BY c.position ASC;

+---------+----+--------+----------+
| row_num | id | name   | position |
+---------+----+--------+----------+
|       1 |  4 | Others |        2 |
|       2 |  2 | Cats   |        3 |
|       3 |  1 | Dogs   |        4 |
|       4 |  3 | Birds  |       10 |
+---------+----+--------+----------+
```

In MySQL 8.0, you'll be able to do this with more standard syntax using  [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html).

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER w AS row_num, c.*
FROM categories AS c 
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY c.position ASC);
```

Gives the same output as the query using the user-variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You think I can make a SELECT trigger that adds the row_num column dynamically ( the query you provided ) ? I should place it AFTER or BEFORE the SELECT query ? Just realized you're an Oracle Director, lucky me :)

Comment: There are no SELECT triggers. Probably what you want is a [VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html). This is a way of storing a complex query kind of like a macro. Then you can query the view like you would a simple table. But be careful to read about how to use ORDER BY in a view.